# Initializing an array

Tags: c++, arrays, initializing

I am doing the following for initializing an array in c++

```
int a;
cin>>a;
float b[a];
```

This works and compiles in my computer. IS this correct? I thought that we can only do this if a was a const int.

Comment: It's a compiler extension, although it's coming in a TS soon. Use `-pedantic(-errors)`.

Comment: @chris could you please elaborate as I am new to this and did not understand your reply. Can i continue coding using this kind of a inititlization?

Comment: The answer elaborates on most of it. Assuming you're using GCC or Clang, you can compile with `-pedantic` to get a warning, and VLAs are coming to C++ in a technical specification in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on you definition of "correct".

This is called **variable-length array** (or just *VLA*) and it's not officially supported in the current versions of C++ (100% sure for C++03 and before, 99.99% sure for C++11), but it is in C.

Some compilers allow this as a compiler extension.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about whether a is a constant int. It's about whether a has a initial value assigned at comipling time. Compiler needs to allocate storage according to a `const int` value. C++ standard doesn't support variable length array right now.

In C99， this syntax of variable length array is valid, but C++ standard says no. It is a very useful feature, leaving all the hairy memory allocating stuff to the compiler.

In GCC and Clang, this feature is supported as a compiler extension, so you won't get any warning and error. But MSVC compiler will put an error message that says `cannot allocate an array of constant size 0`, So it is compiler specific.

The compiler that supports this feature may have convert your code with `new` operator.

```
int a;
cin>>a;
float *b = new float[a];
```

This is valid in C++ standard.

Another thing is that though it is called variable-length array, it is not length-variable at all. Once it is defined, its length is a constant value which never change. You can't expand it or shrink it.

It is much better to use the `vector` container which is truly *length variable*, and with much more scalability and adaptivity.

See the post for more discussion on [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)